# NodeJS create object of function in module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have file item.js

```
exports.itemParam = function(name, price, url, id){
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.id = id;
  this.url = url;
};
```

and in my www.js I require item.js

```
var item = require('../modules/item');
```

Which way can I create object of this function?

```
item.itemParam(a,b,c,k); // item.new itemParam(a,b,c,k); ?
```

When `itemParam` I have in www.js I execute this in

```
new itemParam(a,b,c,k);
```

Comment: Why do you ask instead of testing on your own? `item.itemParam(a,b,c,k);` - this way. But your function doesn't return anything. Make an obejct within it. Give one props and return it.

Comment: Which way? When I get this function in main file I only execute like this `items[k] = new itemParam(a,b,c,k);`

Comment: Alternatively `new item.itemParam(a,b,c,k);` should work.

Comment: Ok it works, there is another way to do this?

Comment: If you defined your class the other way then there would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you gonna keep your class definition, then this will work:

```
new item.itemParam(a,b,c,k);
```

`itemParam` function can't be used in www.js file without referring to the obejct that has one which is `item`.